# Hierarchy visual explication with path

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've got a column "path" with the inner hierarchy like 1|5|115 (1|5, 1|7, 2|7|4 etc..)
and i have another column with the names called "name"
Is it possible (knowing these two columns) to visually explicate contained hierarchy's shift within matrix visual and\or a slicer?
(when within the matrix and\or the slicer i can see correctly foldered list of names)

Comment: If you want to display the hierarchy in a matrix visual, you will need to create separate columns for each hierarchy level (e.g. L1, L2, L3, L4...). Then you will be able to either put these new columns in a visual or form a new hierarchy based on them.

Comment: So, as I understand it, the presence of a DAX function in this case does not matter?

Comment: No, only columns can be used to display detail information (simplifying a bit, rows in columns or slicers).

Comment: For example, https://www.daxpatterns.com/parent-child-hierarchies/